# Why Docker does not destroy the hidden layers?

Tags: docker

Thinking of Docker's Union File System that any change will actually be carried on the current image (the top-most layer) and not the previous ones; The question is why those layers are not destroyed by Docker and just hidden? Is there any specific reason to it?

Comment: Could you clarify what  you mean by the "hidden layers"?

Comment: In order to understand what a Docker volume is, we first need to be clear about how the filesystem normally works in Docker. Docker images are stored as series of read-only layers. When we start a container, Docker takes the read-only image and adds a read-write layer on top. If the running container modifies an existing file, the file is copied out of the underlying read-only layer and into the top-most read-write layer where the changes are applied. The version in the read-write layer hides the underlying file, but does not destroy it — it still exists in the underlying layer.

Comment: from: http://container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

caching

by saving each layer individually, docker can cache the result and re-use it later if it is not invalidated by any previous change.

makes for faster builds, and smaller over-all file system use when having multiple images build from the same base image

Comment: Thanks, just a question about re-using them; don't the previous layers become read-only? I mean could I edit the Dockerfile of three layers back? Thinking of something like version control systems...

Comment: @Vennesa, if you edited the Dockerfile of three layers back, then that and everything past it would have a new hash, thus a new identity -- if this weren't enforced and one changed the value associated with a preexisting identity, you'd have nearly unpredictable side effects on child states, and you'd lose the ability to have an identity refer to a single concrete thing. If you're familiar with how git's tree contains the hashes of all parent commits, it's very much the same concept.

Comment: Also, you find out "for free" what can be safely reused and what can't by this strategy: If you have a stored state with the hash of its parents and its Dockerfile, then you know that its value corresponds with those inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Docker was built on AUFS which is a union file system.

Images are created by layering changes on top of each other via AUFS (other methods have been added since then)

A typical build will [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) something that creates some data and it save in a layer.

```
RUN touch a -- L1       a
RUN touch b -- L2         b
RUN touch c -- L3           c
```

Each layer stores only it's own set of changes.

The sum of these AUFS layers are mounted one on top of each to become the underlying virtual file system for a container. The "Image" is just a view of the data in the underlying layers.

The image itself doesn't store any data. It only references layers which store data.

```
*image view             a b c
L3                          c
L2                        b
L1                      a
```

The container changes are then made in a layer on top of all this. Copying up any existing data from the appropriate layer if it needs to me modified, adding new data into it's layer, or "removing" data which removes the reference to the data, not the actual data in the underlying layer.

If I was to modify a file, create a file, and remove a file

```
echo test >> a
touch d
rm c
```

The layers would look like:

```
Lcontainer              a   * d
L3                          c
L2                        b
L1                      a
```

If you were to destroy one of the lower layers, the view that is presented to the container would be missing that data.

```
*image view             a   c
L3                          c
L1                      a
```

As [Derick Bailey mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43336123/1318694) this allows for some clever image build time caching that allows layers to be shared between images, if the exact same layer is used again. This is normally when you build [`FROM`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) an existing image.

Newer storage drivers like [`decivemapper`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/#reads-with-the-devicemapper) and [`zfs`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/zfs-driver/#container-reads-and-writes-with-zfs) implement the same strategy but do so at the block level with file system snapshots or clones for each layer. Disk blocks that are unchanged from an underlying layer/snapshot will read from the original layer/snapshot. The container layer/snapshot maintains a pointer back to the original data until it is changed or removed.